# End call in android after some time when call is in process programmatically

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to design an App in which I want to end Incoming/outgoing calls after some specific time. I am using `PhoneStateListener` to listen state change of call

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
          public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
          switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                tIncomingCounter=false;
              Log.i(TAG1, "IDLE"+IncomingCounter);
            break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                IncomingCounter=true;
              Log.i(TAG1, "OFFHOOK");
            break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                Log.i(TAG1, "RINGING");
            break;
            }
          } 
        }
```

Comment: You should consider adding a question to your question. Is the code you provided intended to perform the mentioned task? Does it work? If not, what problem are you encountering?